# The submitted form is not saved in sql - dJango

Tags: python, django

I have searched some posts about this issue but still not find solution. After clicking the "submit", the page could redirect to another page. But the sql database doesn't show the submitted information.

Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def input(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            company = form.cleaned_data['company']
            region = form.cleaned_data['region']
            uom= form.cleaned_data['uom']
            start_date= form.cleaned_data['start_date']
            end_date= form.cleaned_data['end_date']
            add_input=Input.objects.create(company=company,region=region,uom=uom,start_date=start_date,end_date=end_date)
            add_input.save()
            return redirect('resut')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = InputForm(initial={'company':'coco','uom':'M$'},instance=Input)
        return render_to_response('inputform.html',{'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```
class Input(models.Model):
    company=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    region=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    uom=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date=models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    end_date=models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

**forms.py**

```
class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    company=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, label="Company",error_messages={'required': 'Please enter your name'},required=True)
    regionlist = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Dupont.objects.values('region').distinct())
    uom=forms.CharField(required=True)
    start_date=forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(),required=True)
    end_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(),required=True)
    error_css_class='error'
    required_css_class = 'required'

    class Meta:
        model = Input
        fields = ('company', 'region','uom','start_date','end_date')
        widgets = {
            'start_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
            'end_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
        }
```

**html snippet**

```
<form action="{% url 'result' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

        <!--company--> 
        <div class="field">
            <p>Company:<input type="text" name="company" value="{{company}}"/>
        </div>


        <!--region-->
        <div class="field" >
            <label> Select the Region:
            {{ form.regionlist }}
                {% for region in form.regionlist.choices %}
                     <option value="{{ val }}" {% ifequal data.val val %}selected {% endifequal %}></option>
                {% endfor %}
            </label>
        </div>

        <!--uome-->
        <div class="field">
            <p>Unit of Measure:<input type="text" name="uom" value="{{uom}}"/>
        </div> 

        <!--start date-->
        <label for="startDate">Start Month:</label>
        <input name="start_date" id="startDate" class="date-picker"/>

        <!--END date-->
        <label for="endDate">End Month:</label>
        <input name="end_date" id="endDate" class="date-picker" />


        <!--submit-->
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p></div>

{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-error">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

  </form>
```

Comment: The indentation in your `forms.py` is wrong. `class Meta:` should be part of `class Inputform(forms.ModelForm):`. Also please follow the conventions and name your forms like this: `InputForm` instead of `Inputform`.

Comment: Your form's action points to a url for `result` does that take you to the `input` view? Also, you have a csrf token so why do you have it as `csrf_exempt`?

Comment: No, the action point to another view, instead of input view. I don't paste that view because the issue now is this form's data doesn't saved successfully.

Comment: In your `views.py` why do you create `add_input`? I think you could do `form.save()`. Or maybe I'm overseeing something.

Comment: I tried the form.save(), it doesn't work, so I used this way , to creat and then save

Comment: I've reverted your edit since it completely changes the question you are asking. If you have another question then you should ask a new question. If my answer solved the problem you were having in this question then you are free to mark it as an accepted answer

Comment: @Sayse Thank you so much Sayse, because I am still struggling with this saving issue, so I didn't mark it yet. I don't quite get the one you said "There is no company field in model"? There are "company", "region"...listed in the model....or maybe you point to another place?

Comment: Try `makemigrations`

Comment: @Sayse,actually, it still doesn't save. But it could redirect to another page(though it is blank page), so I was wondering if this means the form has been validated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No, the action point to another view, instead of input view. I don't paste that view because the issue now is this form's data doesn't saved successfully.

Well then thats your problem, when you submit a form it goes to the specified action. If the snippet is the `inputform.html` as I suspect it is then you just need to delete the action from your form.

```
<form method="post">
```

Comment: the purpose is when user submit the "input" form, then the page will direct to ANOTHER page and show the some information submitted by user.  Sorry I delete the action in html, but it still doesn't save in database.

Comment: @miaomiao - Yes they're welcome to, but you do that from your view, you still need to process the form first. Is the form valid? Try setting a breakpoint if your IDE allows that

Comment: @miaomiao - You can whatever you want to do with the data after you've gotten it. Your form's sole purpose is to gather information, what you do with it afterwards is up to you

Comment: @miaomiao - No, your `Input` model doesn't have a company field. The `csrf_exempt` means that anyone can post your form without a token